# Use UUID as the value for the `sub` claim in Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, access-token, claims-based-identity, laravel-passport

When an access token is generated using Laravel Passport the default user `id` is used as the user identifier, but we don't want to expose the primary key in the JWT.

How can I have the access token use a UUID value (e.g. an extra `subject_id` column in `users` table) for the value of the `sub` claim in a clean way, without having to:

- change the primary key for my `User` model
- change the migrations for the `user_id` in the `oauth_access_tokens` and `oauth_auth_codes` tables

In the [`AccessTokenTrait`](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/8ab731e84eef904b5913ba31b38116acf8ea50b6/src/Entities/Traits/AccessTokenTrait.php#L68) the creation of the JWT is in a private method, so how would you reimplement the `AccessTokenInterface` to have a clean way to use a UUID value for the `sub` claim?